# SQLBulkOperations Error HY092, Invalid Attribute/Option Identifier

Tags: c++, odbc

`SQLBulkOperations` returns `SQLState=HY092`. The message is

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][Invalid Attribute/Option Identifier].
```

I have tried everything, including the latest version of SQL server 2008 R2 Native Client Setup from Microsoft. I have used several differing databases and servers, with the same result. I am essentially using the sample code provided by Microsoft for `SQLBulkOperations`, although I have attempted modification of that code with the same result.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov thanks for tidying the question

Comment: I found the source of the problem. Example code/samples available seldom mention the obvious. The default concurrency is read-only. Changing this with, for example, retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_CONCURRENCY, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_CONCUR_VALUES, 0); saves one from much pain.